# How to display CPU temperature in bash prompt?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cpu, bashrc, temperature

Inspired by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779819/cpu-temperature-embedded-in-bash-command-prompt), I added the following code to `.bashrc`:

```
get_cpu_temperature() {
    CEL=$'\xc2\xb0C'
    temp=$( cat /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp )
    temp=`expr $temp / 1000`
    echo $temp$CEL
}

PS1="$(get_cpu_temperature) \u@\h:\w\$ "
```

However, it appears that this function is only called once, so the temperature is not updated. How can I have an updated temperature reading in the prompt? It doesn't have to update constanty; once per prompt is fine.

Comment: You need to use `PROMPT_COMMAND`.  See [What is the difference between PS1 and PROMPT_COMMAND](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3058390/3030305).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to get `PS1` updated dynamically:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="$(get_cpu_temperature) \u@\h:\w\$ "'
```